# Windows Server 2008 - "No audio devices are installed"

Tags: audio, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to make a music bot for TeamSpeak on Windows Server 2008 using Virtual Audio Cable.

All of my audio devices are listed as 'Working' in Device Manager, yet in the Sound Control Panel it just says "No audio devices are installed".

Suggestions please, thank you in advance.

Comment: Check that the audio service is actually running.

Comment: Yes its running, I also forgot to add I installed the Desktop Experience to see if that was an issue.

Comment: For me it was a combination of turning on the services, and doing the tsclient.msc changes listed in two separate answers below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, managed to solve my problem, I will post it here for people who run into the same issue.

If you use RDP, it disables all audio devices and there appears to be a known bug with newer versions of Windows Server making no available workaround.

So basically, don't use RDP, use something else like VNC or TeamViewer and you'll notice all audio devices become available.

Comment: this is not a solution to dump RDP... Dumbur has a solution in his message. RDP is far superior to TeamViewer and VNC (VNC because it is a pain to configure - especially ultravnc which is buggy) and TeamViewer just plain sucks because it is has limited resolution support

Answer (score 3):

By default audio redirection is disabled on server side in server SKU.

To enable it, run tsconfig.msc on server, double click the connection, go to “Client Settings” tab, uncheck the “Audio” checkbox.

This worked for me

Comment: pure genius - I would have never thought in 1000 years to **uncheck** those

Answer (score 1):

Ensure The Desktop Experience service is installed and in the `Local Resources` tab on the Remote Desktop Connection client under `Remote Audio` click the `Settings` button. Configure the settings to your liking.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue, and RDP was not the issue for me. I set two services to Automatic and started them which resolved the issue and allowed me to play .wav files:

- Windows Audio
- Windows Audio Endpoint Builder

Comment: if that doesn't fix it for you (it does for me on other versions of windows server but not 2008r2), then use Dumbars solution